# Stopping the jumping of text area on clicking the text

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using xeditable grid writtin in angularjs.
When i click on the text to edit it, it resizes my div and it appears like its jumping to a textarea input.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.user = {
    desc: 'Awesome user \ndescription!'
  };
});
```

```css
div[ng-app] { margin: 50px; }

section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<h4>Angular-xeditable Textarea (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div class="section">

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">  <a href="#" editable-textarea="user.desc" e-rows="7" e-cols="40">
{{ user.desc || 'no description' }}
  </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What , i want is to stop the jumping and it should appear smooth.

Attached is the fiddle.

> http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/15405/

help is appreciated.

Comment: A small tip for when you post questions here: please include all relevant code where it says `enter code here`. Do not just link to an external resource, as those can fail eventually and render your question useless to future readers.

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: crome,safari,firefox